# How to get a value in MP Android chart on double tap

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am implementing MP Android Bar chart.Here i need to show two graphs once i clicked on Barchart, means one graph on single tap and other on double tap.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an interface [`OnChartGestureListener`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.java), which contains two handy methods:

[`void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me)`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.java#L40)

[`void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me)`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.java#L47)

Their names speak for themselves. Just invoke appropriate method on [`Chart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java):

[`public void setOnChartGestureListener(OnChartGestureListener l)`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java#L1002)

Example:

```
mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Double", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
```

As parameter you get `MotionEvent`.

To get X and Y values, call:

```
mChart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(me.getX(), me.getY()).getX();
mChart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(me.getX(), me.getY()).getY()
```

it should work for [`BarChart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/BarChart.java). Also remember to disable zooming on double tap:

```
mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
```

However it may not work, as I have seen that for [`PieChart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/PieChart.java) it does not work. Only long press and single press works for it.